# Отличие тревог на комментарии

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, комментарии, тревоги, удаление-комментариев

На ruSO можно помечать комментарии тревогой, вот первые 2 причины на это:

[image: Тревога на комментарий]

***Вопросы следующие:***

- Чем конкретно отличаются эти причины?
- Какие комментарии стоит относить к первой категории, а какие ко второй?
- Есть ли отличия в их технической реализации?
- Какая категория предпочтительнее, если комментарий подходит под обе?

Также мне очень интересно узнать, как эти тревоги обрабатываются в принципе и как происходит непосредственное удаление комментария.

***P. S.:***
В качестве примера, в котором категория однозначно не ясна, хотел привести комментарий из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992186/339283) вопроса, но, пока писал, его уже удалили (довольно оперативно). Не уверен, но думаю, модераторы могут его посмотреть.

Comment: С моей перспективы ничем. В интерфейсе модератора они отображаются одинаково вроде как.

Comment: Там же ссылки на разные параграфы норм поведения: [по первой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks) три абзаца с объяснениями, [по второй](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language) — объяснения и примеры.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На [этой странице Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/383809) разжевывается размежевание этих двух флагов:

> Comments that contain harassment, bigotry or abuse or that are unfriendly or unkind should always be flagged. What you consider rude is subjective, but as a general rule if it is more likely to upset readers than it is to inform them, it qualifies. In deciding between the two flags, consider whether the comment is directly attacking a person (or the content they create) or a group. If so, it's probably appropriate to flag with the first reason. If it contains "pithy" jokes made at the authors' expense or "snarky" advice meant more to score points with the commenter's peers than to inform or educate it's probably a better fit for the second.

что можно свести к (мой перевод-интерпретация-сокращение):

1. *Нетерпимость, травля, оскорбление* – **прямое** воздействие на индивида или группу, или контент ими созданный.
2. *Недружелюбность, враждебность* – злобное подшучиваение, чрезмерно критичные и саркастические советы, направленные более на то, чтобы "выделаться" перед другими комментаторами, нежеле чем улучшить вопрос или проинформировать автора.

Вот оригинальные [пост на Мете о введение новых флагов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/383809). Там есть следующее:

> We've separated attacks on people or groups from general rude behavior and added explanations for each flag type.

---

> Мы отделили атаку на людей или группы людей от в принципе грубоко поведения и добавили объяснения под каждым флагом.

То бишь, в каком то смысле можно воспринимать эти флаги как *уровни нарушения общественного спокойствия*. Ибо сознательная "атака" на конкретную группу людей всегда более "плохо" чем просто грубое поведение.

Теперь по примерам [опять же из Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313552/383809):

**Harassment, bigotry or abuse / Нетерпимость, травля, оскорбление**

> - This code is so bad you should feel bad for even asking about it here.
> - You're an idiot.
> - &#&@(& you and your little pony, too.

---

> - Это такой ужасный код, что вам должно быть стыдно показывать его тут и задавать вопросы.
> - Вы - идиот.
> - Вам стоит пойти на***. Вместе с вашим вопросом.

**Unfriendly or unkind / Недружелюбность и враждебность**

> - This isn't a do-my-homework-for-me site.
> - My question is completely clear! You all are trolling me with these comments!
> - I'm voting to close this because it's just a rant.

---

> - Мы тут не делаем за вас вашу домашнюю работу.
> - Мой вопрос отлично сформулирован. Вы меня просто троллите.
> - Это просто нытье, поэтому я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса.

Кроме того, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks) и [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language) расшифровочка написанная уже на самом RU StackOverflow.

---

Теперь по поводу того, в чем **практическая разница**. Вот в [этом ответе общей Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318549/383809) говорится, примерно, следующее:

> ...there are two flag reasons that relate to negatively received comments. While we give flaggers two different options, they're treated the same by the system.

---

> ...есть две причины тревоги, которые относятся к негативно воспринятым комментариям. Несмотря на то, что мы даем "дружинникам" две разных опции, они обрабатываются системой одинаково.

То есть пока (!) с точки зрения системы и реакции на них они не различимы. Однако, так как в базу данных они записываются по-разному, в будущем это легко может поменяться при необходимости.

Comment: Считаю этот перевод харассментом в адрес пони!

Comment: Вероятнее всего - пони - часть "устойчивого" выражения.